# Firebase query showing wrong data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have user profiles stored in Firebase with a key "Pricing" and some value saved as integer. I also have profiles that DO NOT have that key.

I execute:

```
usersReference = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://someRef")
    .child("users")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "Pricing")
    .queryEnding(atValue: pricingToSearch)
    .observe(...)
```

However, the query result is always showing me also the profiles without that key. How can I exclude them from the search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only telling the query builder to order the data by child 'Pricing' and that the last valid value for 'Pricing' is pricingToSearch. You are not giving it any hint about the first valid value. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#data_order)

```
Children with a nil value for the specified child key come first.
```

Your query will probably work if you just add

```
queryStarting(atValue: 0)
```

so

```
usersReference = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://someRef")
    .child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Pricing")
    .queryStarting(atValue: 0)
    .queryEnding(atValue: pricingToSearch)
    .observe(...)
```

Comment: Great answer @balsick!